# Packages not loading with pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

When I convert a python app into an exe, doesn't load external modules that I loaded in the python file.
Is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pyinstaller main.spec` is ignoring the packages.
The documentation on their official page fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the module PyInstaller may be removing the packages because it can't convert them

Comment: "I think..." cannot be an answer, you can add it as a comment instead.